# Spray File Upload: Unmarshalling MultiPartForm

Tags: scala, unmarshalling, spray

I am learning Spray, using spray-can and spray-httpx (without spray-routing) to accept uploaded files. I have come up with the following:

```
  def receive = {
    ...

    case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/upload"), _, entity, _) =>
      object mp extends MultipartUnmarshallers
      mp.MultipartFormDataUnmarshaller(entity).foreach{ part =>
        for{
          fname <- part.fields.get("Filename").map(_.entity.asString)
          fbody <- part.fields.get("Filedata").map(_.entity.buffer)
        }{
          println(fname+ ": " +fbody.length)
        }       
      }
      sender ! HttpResponse(status = 200)

    ...
  }
```

This works, but I think the Multipart unmarshaller was not meant to be used this way. Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the most elegant, however, it works

```
val e = spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FormDataUnmarshallers.MultipartFormDataUnmarshaller.apply(request.entity)

        e.fold(error => {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not unmarshall multipart form data")
        },
          formdata => {
            for (part <- formdata.fields) {
               //do what you want with the parts
             }
          })
```